# How to deal with GCM error 3006 in Appcelerator

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator

I'm quite at a loss right now. Recently I had to change our **Server Key** and **Sender Id** in an Appcelerator Android app.

Since then I can't get the Push Notifications to work. All I get is a **GCM Error 3006** with the message:

> *The sender_id contained in the registration_id does not match the sender_id used to register with the GCM servers*.

I tried to use `CloudPush.clearStatus()` to reset the credentials but it didn't work. Still the same message.

There's some posts about this, mostly saying to rebuild and redeploy the app to fix it. But this also didn't work.

So any help would be welcome.